# Trouble inserting picture in CV template next to header

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, align, includegraphics

I'm writing my CV using the template
Medium Length Professional CV on https://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv. I would like to add my face, linkedin_pb.jpg, to my CV next to the header information with name, address etc. What modifications do I need to make?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your preamble:

```
%****************************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\document}{%
    \ori@document  
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}{%
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}} %your photo <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}{%   
            \printname % Print the name specified with \name
        \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{ % Print the first address if specified
            \printaddress{\@addressone}}
        \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{ % Print the second address if specified
            \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}
        \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{}{ % Print the third address if specified
            \printaddress{\@addressthree}}}
    \end{minipage}\hspace*{0.25\linewidth}
}
\makeatother
% ****************************************************************
```

Adjust the size of your picture with `\scale=...`

[image: a]

Use `\hspace*{1.5em }\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image} }%your photo <<<<` to indent the photo as the items inside the sections.

[image: c]